# Anyone have a Mathematica Graphics3D to three.js converter?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, three.js

I'd like to render Mathematica Graphics3D in three.js and avoid the frontend of Mathematica altogether.

Comment: If you can explain to us what three.js is and exactly what format you need the data converted into (with examples), then we might be able to come up with something.  If you need to put 3D graphics on the web, then I'd suggest LiveGraphics3D http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/ for Mathematica versions <= 5.2 or JavaView http://www.javaview.de/ for any other version.  They're already integrated with Mathematica and are a lot more portable than anything WebGL based.  E.g. on my old laptop WebGL only "works" in Windows Firefox, other browsers (Chrome) disable it ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Or explain what Mathematica is for those following the three.js tag! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaView to convert LiveGraphics3D to OBJ. Three.js comes with a Python script that can convert OBJ files to a JSON description, which, in turn, can be loaded with three.js.

Answer (score 0):

The "WLJS Notebook" project is actively working on it:

- Website: https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/
- GitHub: https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend